# Setting value for one column of all records in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to clear one column for all records in my table.
For example, if my table had three columns: `id`, `comment`, and `likes` - I would like to be able to clear the `likes` column.

```
+---+-------+-----+
|id |comment|likes|
+-----------------+
|1  |hi     |3    |
|2  |hello  |12   |
|3  |hey    |1    |
+---+-------+-----+
```

so that afterwards it would look like this:

```
+---+-------+-----+
|id |comment|likes|
+-----------------+
|1  |hi     |     |
|2  |hello  |     |
|3  |hey    |     |
+---+-------+-----+
```

I'm guessing I would have to use MySQL `UPDATE` to clear the `likes` value, but how do I iterate through all records and keep the `id` and `comment` fields the same?

I don't want to change each record manually.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table SET likes = NULL
```

or if your `likes` column does not allow `NULL`:

```
UPDATE your_table SET likes = ''
```

Some SQL tools that are used for executing DB queries prevent updates on ALL records (queries without a `where` clause) by default. You can configure that and remove that savety setting or you can add a `where` clause that is `true` for all records and update all anyway like this:

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET likes = NULL
WHERE 1 = 1
```

If you **compare** with `NULL` then you also need the `IS` operator. Example:

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET likes = NULL
WHERE likes IS NOT NULL
```

because **comparing** `NULL` with the equal operator (`=`) returns *UNKNOWN*. But the `IS` operator can handle `NULL`.

Comment: That last info about the `where` option - Thanks!

Comment: 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0012 seconds.)
update `trips` set driver_id = 1 where driver_id = NULL

Comment: this is worked update your_table 
set likes = null
where 1 = 1 as well but how can i set random number

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi: `where driver_id = NULL` does not work. Replace it with `where driver_id IS NULL`

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi: When **comparing** with `null` you need the `is` operator.