# How to set all values in a single column MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I've made a new tuple called 'description' in a table.

Just want a query to set all the 'description' tuples for my already created data to a certain piece of text.

E.g. of fundamental 'update' query, but not sure if it is not the right method to use:

```
UPDATE suppliers SET name = 'HP'WHERE name = 'IBM';
```

Comment: Have you tried? It seems to be correct. That query will change all the records for the `name` column on the `suppliers` table where the value was `IBM`

Comment: That was just an example, I want to update all the fields in the column name. Would UPDATE suppliers SET name = 'HP' work?

Comment: again, why don't you try? it must, since it is like an implicit `WHERE TRUE`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting value for one column of all records in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364200/setting-value-for-one-column-of-all-records-in-table)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sorted

I used the following query:

```
UPDATE suppliers SET description = 'business'
```

This sets all the description FIELDS values in my table to the string "business".

Comment: You seem to be misusing the term *tuple*. At least, what you are calling a *tuple* in both your question and your answer is normally called a *column*.

Answer (score 14):

The formatting of the query you've provided is correct. Before running an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` it's always wise to run a `SELECT` of that query to make sure that is the change you want to make.

Your test query would be:

```
SELECT name FROM suppliers WHERE name = 'IBM';
```

However, the query you've provided will not update the `description` column. To do this, you would need something like:

```
UPDATE suppliers SET description = 'HP' WHERE name = 'IBM';
```

After executing this `UPDATE`, you can run this query to validate your result:

```
SELECT name, description FROM suppliers WHERE name = 'IBM';
```

Comment: Good advice.  I even go as far as to append a LIMIT 1 when I know it should only impact a single row.

Answer (score -1):

This will change the filed status = "deactivate" where table name is :- user

```
 Session session=null;
    int rows=0;
     try {
           session =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
           Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE user  SET status = 'deactivate'");
           rows = query.executeUpdate();
         //  result = query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To update the 'description' column for all tuples in a table with a certain piece of text, you can use the following query:

UPDATE your_table_name SET description = 'Your desired text';

Replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table, and 'Your desired text' with the specific text you want to set for the 'description' column.

Comment: this answer has been already provided