# PHP/MySQL: updating every row with a random value - foreach not working (updating all rows with same value)

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-update

I have around 1000 records in my MySQL database. I recently added a new column called **UniqueKey** and I want to update all rows in my table with a random, unique key.

This is what I got:

```
$updatequery = "SELECT * FROM pictures";
    $resultt = $conn->query($updatequery);

    while ($roww = $resultt->fetch_array()) {
        $rowws[] = $roww;
    }

    foreach($rowws as &$roww) {
        $UniqueKey = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 6);
        $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdate);

    }
```

The problem here is as follows. It DOES create a **UniqueKey**, but it uploads this new random value to ALL my rows. How can I  do this?:

- generate random key by $UniqyeKey
- Insert this key in the first row
- regenerate a new key and insert this in the next row
- etc etc

Thanks in advance! Have been trying to fix this for hours..

Comment: Why are you creating `$rowws` and not just doing the while in the place of the foreach?

Comment: Seems like you thought if you passed `$roww` as reference you could manipulate the data in the database via the reference to the original item. Cute, but that doesn't work. You'd only be changing the local copy of those values in the array in PHP. The values in the SQL database aren't affected unless you do specific SQL update commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use the extra `foreach` loop. You can do the all the job within the `while` loop itself, as follows:

```
 while ($roww = $resultt->fetch_array()) {
       $UniqueKey = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 6);
        $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey' WHERE id = '".$roww['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdate);
    }
```

**Note:** The given example assumes that `id` is the Primary Key in your table. You can change that accordingly

Related: [Setting value for one column of all records in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364200/setting-value-for-one-column-of-all-records-in-table)

Comment: Exactly, OP doesn't tell the SQL server *which* item he wants to `UPDATE.`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the support and help, it's really appreciated! Thank you @Anant for a more elaborate explanation/improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Without a `where` clause an update updates all the records. So update your query from:

```
UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey'
```

to:

```
UPDATE pictures 
SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey' 
where id = ?
```

or something like that where it identifies the one record you want to update each time.

Also you don't need the `foreach`, do it all in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The others have already solved the issue with updating all rows at once. 
But if you truly want to have unique values, I would suggest to add a UNIQUE constraint to your UniqueKey column.

In addition, you could put your generation of the unique key and the update query in a do-while loop like this:

```
while ($roww = $resultt->fetch_array()) {
    do {
          $UniqueKey = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 6);
          $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey' WHERE id = '".$roww['id']."'";
    } while (!mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdate))
}
```

The combination of these two steps would ensure that the key is Unique and is properly inserted in the database.

Comment: whatever you want to suggest, suggest it with `while`. `foreach` is not necessary at all in his case. It's just increase of burden

Comment: Why the `do-while`?

Comment: do-while would mean that this would happen at least once. So practically it does the following: generates a key, generates a query, executes an update query. If the update query breaks, it would most probably break because the key is a duplicate - i.e. already has been generated before and inserted for another id. Of course, it could break for other reasons - server down, etc. No matter why it breaks, mysqli_query() would return false. Then the do-while loop repeats - generates a new key and tries inserting it again.

Comment: P.S. Note that it would only work if you add a UNIQUE constraint to your UniqueKey column. To be actually able to add this constraint, the UniqueKey values should be unique in the first place. You can achieve that by the following query (executed just once):
 `UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = id`
Assuming id is your primary key.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a Where clause to update the rows you want. Foreach only loops you through the result set you get from the select, you are not actually inside the database. When you do

```
$updatequery = "SELECT * FROM pictures";
$resultt = $conn->query($updatequery);
```

You are assigning to $resultt the result of that query, you are not actually 'inside' the database. When you then query:

```
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdate);
```

You are updating ALL UniqueKeys to the same one. Your foreach loop does nothing, it only loops through your result set and updates the key $rowss times. Basically, you are updating all keys #rowss times. I assume you have an autoincrementing ID in your table?

If so, you can delete your foreach loop and replace it with:

```
$idresult = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM pictures");

while ($row = $idresult->fetch_assoc()){
   mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey' WHERE id = " . $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're updating every single row because you're not using a WHERE clause.

Do something like this:

```
foreach($rowws as &$roww) {
  $UniqueKey = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 6);
  $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pictures SET UniqueKey = '$UniqueKey' WHERE primary_key=".$rowws['primary_key'];
  mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdate);
}
```

Where `primary_key` is the PK column of your table.

Comment: No problemo, señor!

Comment: @PhiterFernandes no need of `foreach` at all

Comment: Yep I know that. But OP's original code work like this. I used it as an example.

Comment: @JuliusSecret, I recommend you use Anant 's answer since it's better for your performance, even if my solution worked.